# Is this wire puzzle correctly assembled?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles, solvability

I was given this puzzle some years ago and have never found the solution. Recently I picked it up again and have been trying for days to solve it.

[image: Mystery Wire Puzzle]

I presume that the goal is to remove the ring on the right, but I am not sure.

I am looking to find out:

1. The name of the puzzle, if it has one.
2. Whether or not the puzzle is correctly assembled, so I know I am not wasting my time trying to solve it. (It is possible to gently force the ring over the gate it is behind to remove it)

I have spent some time on google image search looking for this puzzle but have come up empty. I am not sure my searches are very good as I don't know the proper way to describe the features of the puzzle either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My googling had a bit more success. It matches the puzzle found [on this site](http://www.zoyotoy.com/blog/project/metal-wire-puzzle-zy1374/), where it is called "Metal wire puzzle ZY1374".

[image]

It is complete, and the aim is to get the ring off, but the starting position has the ring surrounding the loose arm of the puzzle, and the "gate" should go around the doubled-up part of the body.